# Can you contact PI (informally) about the decision timeline of the postdoc?

Tags: postdocs, job-search, interview

I had a postdoc interview more than 2 weeks ago where the panel told me that they will not be avalaible due the entire next week (Easter holiday) and I should expect a decision a week later (or 2 weeks later, can't remember).

The one week time-frame has passed and HR didn't reply to the email I've sent, I am thinking of contacting the potential PI directly (asking and verifying the decision time). I am not sure however if this is an okay move?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its depends what you mean by "okay". You can certainly ask, and you will not face any consequences beyond possibly some mild irratation on the part of the PI, but unlikely sufficient to damage anyone's chances of anything.

However, you are probably also unlikely to gain anything. The most likely situations are:

1. The position has been offered to someone else, but they have yet to make a decision, and other candidates have not yet been informed because you might still be offered the position if the first choice turns it down.
2. Some paper work is missing form some candidate (e.g. a reference) and a decision cannot be made until it is available.

In both cases, its unlikely the PI will be in a position to offer a more concrete time line.

Comment: Wow, hold on..they did told me during the interview that in the first week nothing will happen because of the holidays. So, this should roll out the first scenerio (I guess?), because otherwise this would mean that they did offer the position to someone else during that first week; which should be unlikely, especially that we're at the start of the second week.. :/

Comment: No. You said it was 2 week since the interview. If nothing happened in the 1st week, and then they made an offer to someone else in the second week, they may still be waiting for a reply.